# Error during cassandra initialization when using a custom conf file

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to initialize cassandra using a custom conf file, but I keep having the error:

```
Exception (java.lang.ClassCastException) encountered during startup: 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

I'm adding an screenshot of the error, below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpuOi.png

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thx for the answers.

Comment: Please add relevant source code to your question

Comment: Can you add your yaml file? Also check spacing against an example file. If I remember correctly it might throw a fit if you have extra space. "cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'" is different from " cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'"